# Disable Windows 8 IE10+ default "touch-enabled" dropdownlist functionality

Tags: html, css, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

If we use a simple HTML Select element:

```
<select>
<option>One</option>
<option>Two</option>
<option>Three</option>
<option>Four</option>
<option>Five</option>
<option>Six</option>
<option>Seven</option>
</select>
```

And view this element in IE10+ on a Windows 8 touch-enabled tablet, we find that when the user presses on the drop-down the list repeats, starting at the top of the list again. I understand this is the default functionality but I've been asked to disable it, and stop/snap to the last element. Despite my research and efforts I haven't been able to disable the repeating scroll.

I tried `-ms-scroll-chaining` but that didn't work (further found that it doesn't apply to my situation), per this [link](http://timwhitlock.info/blog/2012/11/touch-screen-swipe-scroll/) "`-ms-scroll-chaining` ...prevents the entire page from swiping when the scroll area is fully at one end." Other examples discuss XAML solutions (e.g., updating a combobox `ItemPanelTemplate` elements `CarouselPanel` to `StackPanel`) which doesn't help me because my issue is in an MVC web-page using HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 2):

I think that such behavior is going to be expected by W8-touch users and **it should not be prevented.**

I doubt that there is an option just for that. If that really bothers you (or your client) you should be able to "solve it" by using javascript-based `<select>`-replacement solutions like [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).

Comment: I appreciate your comment. Per request we're to use our standard dropdown's. To the point that we had to pull our KendoUI (thirdparty... which don't have this problem by the way) from the solution. So unfortunately that is not an option.

Comment: That's an unusual (but welcome) request by them. It's strange that they would stop that specific behavior, though. Also it looks like [`-ms-scroll-chaining`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh466007.aspx) is unrelated and to be used on non-replaced elements (replaced elements are buttons, inputs, selects, etc)

Comment: Agreed, I too prefer a fluent experience. But they've asked me to solve the problem and am seemingly falling short, looking to the community now for an answer. Also, I'm still throwing everything I've got at it research and trial and error.